# Can't set input checked="checked" via jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button, each

I have a table whose rows contain radio button groups like so:

```
<td class="usegsm">
  <input type="hidden" class="use-gsm" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "use_gsm") %>' />
  <input type="hidden" class="use-gsm-lineup" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "use_gsm_lineup") %>' />
  <input type="radio" id="radio1-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>" name="radio-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>" class="events-lineups" />
  <label for="radio1-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>">Events &amp; Lineups</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>" name="radio-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>" class="events" />
  <label for="radio2-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>">Events</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>" name="radio-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>" class="none" checked="checked" />
  <label for="radio3-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MatchId") %>">None</label>
</td>
```

When the page loads (inside document.ready) I call this function to check the correct radio buttons, based on the above values for `input.use-gsm` and `input.use-gsm-lineup`:

```
function setGsmButtonStates() {
      $('td.usegsm').buttonset(); /* http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio */
      $('td.usegsm').each(function(i) {
        var use_gsm = $(this).children('input.use-gsm').val();
        var use_gsm_lineup = $(this).children('input.use-gsm-lineup').val();

        if (use_gsm == 'Y' && use_gsm_lineup == 'Y') {
          $(this).children('input.events-lineups').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else if (use_gsm == 'Y' && use_gsm_lineup != 'Y') {
          $(this).children('input.events').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {
          $(this).children('input.none').attr('checked', true);
        }

      });
    }
```

For some reason setting `.attr('checked',true)` or even `.attr('checked','checked')` has no effect.

Am I using `$.each()` or `.attr()` incorrectly?

Comment: You are using `.attr()` fine I think, which means the issue is liable to be nothing being selected.  `.children()` only matches immediate children, try changing it to `.find()` and see if it works.  Does `.buttonset()` wrap the inputs perhaps?

Comment: Based on his example code, .children() should be returning the correct elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is because buttonset hides the radio buttons with span element. Moving teh call to buttonset to end would solve your problem.

```
function setGsmButtonStates() { 
      $('td.usegsm').each(function(i) { 
        var use_gsm = $(this).children('input.use-gsm').val(); 
        var use_gsm_lineup = $(this).children('input.use-gsm-lineup').val(); 

        if (use_gsm == 'Y' && use_gsm_lineup == 'Y') { 
          $(this).children('input.events-lineups').attr('checked', true); 
        } 
        else if (use_gsm == 'Y' && use_gsm_lineup != 'Y') { 
          $(this).children('input.events').attr('checked', true); 
        } 
        else { 
          $(this).children('input.none').attr('checked', true); 
        } 

      }); 
            $('td.usegsm').buttonset(); /* http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio */ 
    }
```

P.S: I assume that you would call this function once only during the page load.

Comment: GENIUS!!! It actually wraps the text in the label with a <span class="ui-button-text">, not the input itself. I would never in a million years have thought to do that. Regardless, I still can't check the radio buttons imperatively, but the visual effect is what I'm after, since I'm not posting a form back.

Answer (score 1):

First, and I don't think this will solve your issue, use `.attr('checked', 'checked')`.

Then, I'm not sure if jQuery polls the radio buttons constantly to determine if their labels need to be updated, but I'd guess that it doesn't.  Use Firebug (or equivalent tool) and I'll bet you'll see that the checkboxes actually are being checked in the DOM, but the label styles are not being updated to reflect it.

If that's indeed true, you need to manually add the 'ui-state-active' class to the checkbox's label so that the jQuery UI button appears to be selected. (Be sure to remove that same class from all other labels in the set beforehand.)